Shell object and curl
I'm trying to use the following curl command in puredata with the shell object to retrieve an image:
curl -O -k 'https://cdn.onemars.net/sites/perfect-fit_uk_Z61CM_JAs8/image/editor/ben-griffiths-vqeoowvzzys-unsplash_1686909408862.jpg'

This works fine in my terminal. When I do the equivalent in puredata (code below) it tells me it retrieves the image, I get a 1 returned on done, but no image saves to my computer.
#N canvas 0 23 821 330 12;
#X obj 243 123 shell;
#X obj 275 163 print DONE;
#X obj 225 183 print;
#X msg 241 38 curl -O -k 'https://cdn.onemars.net/sites/perfect-fit_uk_Z61CM_JAs8/image/editor/ben-griffiths-vqeoowvzzys-unsplash_1686909408862.jpg'
;
#X connect 0 0 2 0;
#X connect 0 1 1 0;
#X connect 3 0 0 0;

Where Am I going wrong here?

You're using the -O option to curl, which saves the retrieved object to a file on disk named after the end of the URL. Perhaps PureData requires you to put it in a specific place? Or output it to standard output instead of any file?

I have tried curl -k 'https://cdn.onemars.net/sites/perfect-fit_uk_Z61CM_JAs8/image/editor/ben-griffiths-vqeoowvzzys-unsplash_1686909408862.jpg' > '/Users/username/cattest.jpg, again works in terminal, fails in puredata.

The redirection on the end means you're still putting it into a file. Why are you putting it into a file at all? isn't the goal for puredata to load it?

My goal is to put it into a file and save it to a folder. There will ultimately be several images downloaded and Puredata will alternate displaying images.

the problem you are having is that you use single-quotes in your message.
typically, you would use single-quotes in a shell, in order to prevent the shell from interpreting various characters (like space, asterisk,...).
however, with Pd, each atom of the message is passed as a separate argument, so there's no need to use quotes.
in fact, with your invocation you tell curl to literally open an URL 'https://cdn.onemars.net/sites/perfect-fit_uk_Z61CM_JAs8/image/editor/ben-griffiths-vqeoowvzzys-unsplash_1686909408862.jpg', and curl does not really know what to do with these quotes.
if you run Pd in a console, you will see an error:
curl: Failed to extract a sensible file name from the URL to use for storage
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

if you instead omit the quotes, it will magically work.

Good to know. I got so frustrated trying to get this to work that I ended up finding a solution via lua in Ofelia. Works very well and integrated seamlessly with what I was doing.
